# What does `if __FILE__ == $0` mean in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  $:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..')
```

I found this code in Ruby, what's the meaning?

Comment: FYI rubocop wants that to be `$PROGRAM_NAME` instead of `$0`. This is lame IMO.

Answer (score 61):

```
# Only run the following code when this file is the main file being run
# instead of having been required or loaded by another file
if __FILE__==$0
  # Find the parent directory of this file and add it to the front
  # of the list of locations to look in when using require
  $:.unshift File.expand_path("../../", __FILE__)  
end
```

Note that this particular practice (adding to the LOAD_PATH directory) is not usually necessary with the advent of `require_relative`, and `expand_path` is a simpler way of finding the parent directory.

Comment: Very good answer, I'd just suggest noting the meanings of the constants though.  `__FILE__` : this files name, `$0` : the main file that was run, `$:` : LOAD_PATH

Answer (score 37):

#### It's a couple of Ruby Mini-Design-Patterns

It means:

- IF the file is being executed directly, i.e., as a script,
- THEN find the directory the script is in and prepend it to beginning of the load/require search path

The conditional part can be useful for many things. A Ruby file could be written to provide functionality for a large program but also be available (with the extra code) as a script. Alternatively, the script-form could run the module's tests, while the component form implements some class for a bigger program and calls the tests only if referenced by name.

The path prepend has some general uses, besides the obvious one of finding private includes. If you have several different versions or releases of something, this way any companion "executables" (scripts) will get called preferentially.  /usr/local/release232/bin/whatever will run everything from the same bin directory, even if release220 is earlier on the default path.

Comment: Amazing answer... for those who are curious where the docs for some of those cryptic variables are: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html

Answer (score 18):

A great explanation on what/why from ruby-lang.org:

> `__FILE__` is the magic variable that contains the name of the current file. `$0` is the name of the file used to start the program. 
>   **This check says “If this is the main file being used…”** This allows a file to be used as a library, and not to execute code in that context, but if the file is being used as an executable, then execute that code.

See: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/

Answer (score 14):

Ruby, like any language, has some reserved keywords including `if`, `return`, `class`; one of them happens to be `__FILE__`. Ruby uses `__FILE__` to hold the current source file name.

A prepended `$` on a variable's name indicates a global variable. In this case, `$0` contains the name of the script being executed. For example, if you run `ruby hello_world.rb`, the value of `$0` would be `hello_world.rb`

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  ...
end
```

Now code inside the if statement will only be executed when the file that contains the source code is the same file you are executing. For better explanation let's create 2 files.

First `hello_world.rb`:

```
# hello_world

puts "Hello world"
```

and second `hello_pluto.rb`:

```
# hello_pluto

require_relative "hello_world"
puts "Hello Pluto"
```

Here if you run `ruby hello_world.rb`, it will simply output:

```
Hello world
```

Now if you run `ruby hello_pluto.rb`, it will output:

```
Hello world
Hello Pluto
```

It actually runs the file hello_world as well. Now stick the code from hello_world inside the if statement and run hello_pluto again:

```
# hello_world

if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "Hello world"
end
```

As expected, the only thing you see being printed is `Hello Pluto`. So, that if statement guarantees that any code that lies within the statement will only run if the source file is the same as the script you are running.

Ref: [http://periclestheo.com/2014/02/what-is-up-with-**FILE**-and-](http://periclestheo.com/2014/02/what-is-up-with-__FILE__-and-)$0.html

Answer (score 11):

I recommend you use `$PROGRAM_NAME` alias over `$0` since it’s a little clearer what you mean when you use it—they mean the same thing.

Now, what does `$PROGRAM_NAME`/`$0` mean? [From the Ruby docs](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/globals_rdoc.html):

> **$0**
>   Contains the name of the script being executed. May be assignable.

Let’s demonstrate how this works with code.

#### 1. Create hello.rb

```
module Hello
  def self.world
    puts "Hello, world!"
    puts "$0       = #{$0}"
    puts "__FILE__ = #{__FILE__}"
  end
end

if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  puts Hello.world
end
```

Look what happens if you run this file by itself:

```
$ ruby hello.rb
Hello, world!
$0       = hello.rb
__FILE__ = hello.rb
```

#### 2. Create a Rakefile

```
require 'rake'
require_relative 'hello'

task :hello do
  Hello.world
end
```

Now execute this same code from within the context of a Rake task:

```
$ rake hello
Hello, world!
$0       = /Users/sean/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rake
__FILE__ = /Users/sean/Projects/hello/hello.rb
```

Wrapping code at the end of a Ruby file in a `if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__` conditional is an idiom many developers use to say “only execute this code if you’re running this file individually”.

What kind of code would you wrap in this conditional? I often use it to demonstrate how to use a module. This also makes it very convenient to execute this file in isolation to make sure it works outside the context of the larger program you may be writing.

If you didn’t wrap your example code in this conditional, then it would get executed whenever the file is required/loaded in the lifecycle of your larger program, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Where is `$PROGRAM_NAME` documented?

Answer (score 5):

this means that if file was run directly, not required or loaded then add scripts parent directory to $LOAD_PATH (path where ruby search for files that are require()d)