# How can I access source file location of a Ruby class at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'd like to access the source of a class like so:

```
# Module inside file1.rb
module MetaFoo
  class << Object
    def bar
      # here I'd like to access the source location of the Foo class definition
      # which should result in /path/to/file2.rb
    end
  end
end

# Class inside another file2.rb
class Foo
  bar
end
```

I could do something bad like:

```
self.send(:caller)
```

and try to parse the output, or even:

```
class Foo
  bar __FILE__
end
```

But that's not, want I want, I had the hope there is a more elegant solution for that.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: You can access the location of the source of a method, but asking for the location for a class is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling:

`caller.first`

That will print off the file name and line number. Using your demonstration files above (with slight modifications:

*file1.rb:*

```
module MetaFoo
  class << Object
    def bar
      puts caller.first # <== the magic...
    end
  end
end
```

*file2.rb:*

```
require './file1.rb'

class Foo
  bar
end
```

When I run `ruby file2.rb`, I get the following output:

```
nat$ ruby file2.rb 
file2.rb:4:in `<class:Foo>'
```

That's what you want, right?

Comment: Nat, that was it, some RegEx KungFu and I have what I needed. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Both `$0` and `__FILE__` will be useful to you.

`$0` is the path of the running application.

`__FILE__` is the path of the current script.

So, `__FILE__` will be the script or module, even if it's been `required`.

Also, `__LINE__` might be useful to you.

See "[What does `__FILE__` mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby)", "[What does `if __FILE__ == $0` mean in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687680/what-does-if-file-0-mean-in-ruby)" and "[What does `class_eval <<-“end_eval”, __FILE__, __LINE__` mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496102/what-does-class-eval-end-eval-file-line-mean-in-ruby?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: Tin Man, thank you for your input. The problem in fact is, that the definition of bar resides inside a module, and the class Foo is located in a different file. So when method bar is called from within Foo, self is Foo, but __FILE__ is the location of the module which has the bar method definition inside. __LINE__ behaves the same way, and $0 does not seem to provide the info I need at that time. Anyway, thank you for yout help.